# NodeJs express.io Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: node.js, express

i'm newbie in nodejs and express.io, i'm trying to use express.io sample to testing broadcast but i get this error and i can not fix it

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://file/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1424977776399-0. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

sample code:

```
app = require('express.io')()
app.http().io()

// Broadcast the new visitor event on ready route.
app.io.route('ready', function(req) {
    req.io.broadcast('new visitor')
})

// Send client html.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client.html')
})

app.listen(7076)
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

io = io.connect()

// Send the ready event.
io.emit('ready')

// Listen for the new visitor event.
io.on('new visitor', function() {
    $('body').append('<p>New visitor, hooray! ' + new Date().toString() +'</p>')
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing a CORS issue. Given a page loaded from a domain A you can't make, for security reasons, requests to a domain B without consent of the domain B. See http://acuriousanimal.com/blog/2011/01/27/working-with-the-javascript-xmlhttprequest-object/ for better explanation.

I never used express.io framework, but it is probably making requests call based on XMLHttpRequest.

You must enable `cors` module (see https://github.com/techpines/express.io/issues/117) or what is the same, attach `Access-Control-Allow-*` to the responses of your server.